# How to add physics in animation

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have a rigged 3D model and the pre-recorded animation, and now I want to add some physics to the model. For example, when the model is moving and run into obstacles, collisions are expected, and I hope the pre-recorded animation can change according to the simulation. How can I do that? Simply setting the model as **Rigid Body** seems not to work.

Comment: did u try set rigid body to passive and check animated, shape to mesh? if that does not work, pls provide blend file with these settings set and so we can check it out. Since you didn't show us any settings what you have done we cannot really help you instead of just guessing or you watch some yt rigid body beginner tutorials.

Comment: I tried but it did not work. I provide the file in a [new question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275441/enable-physics-in-animation)